# Draggable element should stay in the stop moving point when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery

When the element (id="draggable") stop dragging, the position of the element will be sent to the database via 'mapDemo.php'. Currently the element will go back to the start moving point  if refreshing the page . What I want to do is the element should stay in the stop moving point when page is refreshed.

Below is my code, what change should I do to solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
                    stop: function(){
                          var position = $(this).position();
                          $.ajax({
                                  type:"post",
                                  url:"mapDemo.php",
                                  data: { top: position.left, left: position.top },
                                  cache:false
                                 });
                         }
                    });
        });
        </script>

            <div class="demo">
                <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
                    <p>Drag</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: BTW you realise your code saves left as top and top as left?

Answer (score 0):

If you save the position when its dropped, you need to just restore this position when the page loads.

ie, you could add this line

```
$('#draggable').css({top:200,left:100});
```

with top and left read from wherever you save the data to.